# How to manually find and delete orphaned records - two tables?

Tags: sql

I have made a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a67558/1

Due to external constraints, the IDs (EID and DID) were not specified with a PK. I feel like I am close but SQL is throwing syntax errors, problem may be with the program?

The goal is to remove the row where EID = 100 from tableJoin after the record is deleted from the employee table using a trigger.

Edit per Andrew's comment:

I have tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeOrphan
AFTER DELETE ON employee
FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM joinTable.* FROM employee
RIGHT JOIN tableJoin ON employee.eid=tableJoin.eid
WHERE employee.eid IS NULL;

DELETE FROM employee
WHERE employee.eid = 100;
```

The record is succesfully removed from the employee table but persists in the tableJoin.

Comment: You should show the code in your question rather than using an external site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM joinTable WHERE EID NOT IN (SELECT eid FROM employee)
```

This would be a separate call and would clean up ALL orphans, but if you trigger it regularly it should be a fairly quick process.

Comment: This is what I thought the OP was asking and I was going to write something similar.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a `NOT IN`/`NOT EXISTS`, within a trigger you got access to the deleted row:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeOrphan
AFTER DELETE ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM joinTable WHERE `eid` =  old.`eid`;
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bce02/1)

Comment: This works on the fiddle, however I am getting a syntax error on Postrgresql "PostgreSQL said: syntax error at or near "DELETE"". Tried without the ` on eid but problem persists

Comment: @RobertTan: Why do you create a `mysql` fiddle when you need PG syntax? Seems like in PG you need to wrap the modifying logic in a Function/Procedure and then `EXECUTE` it: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: I had issues installing MySQL and used PG as proxy, I am sorry for the trouble